# C言語で、unsigned charの文字列を比較したいのです

Tags: c

C言語で、main関数を書いています。
送られてきた情報を区切るところまで出来ているのですが、その最初の文字が7Eで始まっているかをifで書きたいです。ただ、うまくいかず教えていただきたいです。

unsigned char buffの先頭が7Eになるはずなので、
　if(strcmp(buff,"7E",2)==0){
  かと思ったのですが、unsigned charではstrcmp使えないし、分からなくなってしまいました。C言語は最近勉強しだしたので、わからないことだらけです。
すみませんが、宜しくお願い致します。

```
 static void tty-read(void)
    {
     int i =0;
　　unsigned char buff[1024];
    size-t len;
    TTYnitBlock(0x7E, 1,2,0,0,1);
    for(;;)
    len=TTYReadFrame(ttyfd, buff, 1024);
    if(len<0){
      fprintf(stderr, "TTYReadFrame %zd %d\n", len, errno);
      exit(1);
    }
     printf("Frame:%d len=%zd|n", i++, len);
     dump-packet(buff, len);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

先頭の値が0x7Eであることを調べるなら以下のようになります。

```
    if(buff[0] == 0x7E){
```

文字通り"7E"をチェックするのであれば、キャストしてstrcmpで構いません。

```
    if(strncmp((char const *)buff,"7E",2)==0){
```

Answer (score 0):

`memcmp`を使うか、より安全な自作関数`contains`を使うことをおすすめします。

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

/**
 * bytesの先頭にtargetが含まれていたらtrue, 含まれていなければfalseを返す
 */
static bool
contains(const unsigned char *bytes,
         uint32_t bytes_size,
         const unsigned char *target,
         uint32_t target_size) {
    uint32_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < bytes_size && i < target_size; ++i) {
        if (bytes[i] != target[i]) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return i == target_size;
}

/**
 * テスト
 */
void
test(void) {
    assert(contains("7E****", 6, "7E", 2));
    assert(!contains("7F****", 6, "7E", 2));
    assert(!contains("7F", 2, "7EE", 3));
    assert(contains("777", 3, "777", 3));
    assert(!contains("777", 3, "333", 3));
}

int
main(void) {
    unsigned char buf[1024] = "7E****";

    // 一番簡単な方法
    if (buf[0] == '7' && buf[1] == 'E') {
        puts("easy");
    }

    // memcmpを使った方法
    if (memcmp(buf, "7E", 2) == 0) {
        puts("memcmp");
    }

    // containsを使った方法
    if (contains(buf, sizeof buf, "7E", 2)) {
        puts("contains");
    }

    test();

    return 0;
}
```